# How to make doubly linked list design more efficient?

Tags: performance, c, linked-list, mergesort

I have played recently and implemented doubly linked list with merge sort algorithm. I was wondering if there is any way of improving the algorithm further to make it as fast as possible (I know about implementing list as array of `void*` pointers but I want to implement that as a separate structure).

I've gone from something like merge sort in [learn C the hard way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex33.html) and added list_split function to split list in half and improved merging so it only links lists together without calling list_push/list_pop procedure which uselessly call calloc and free. That way I was able to get from ~3.3s to 0.9s needed for sorting 1,000,000 integers in list.

Also any comments about style and hints for possible bugs are welcome.

src/dllist.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include "dllist.h"

struct node {
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
    void *data;
};

struct list {
    unsigned int count;
    struct node *first;
    struct node *last;
};

List list_create()
{
    List l;

    l = calloc(1, sizeof(*l));
    assert(l);
    return l;
}

void list_destroy(List l)
{
    free(l);
}

static inline void list_bond(struct node *first, struct node *second)
{
    first->next = second;
    second->prev = first;
}

void list_push_first(List l, void *data)
{
    struct node *n;

    n = calloc(1, sizeof(*n));
    assert(n);
    n->data = data;
    if(l->count > 1) {
        list_bond(n,l->first);
        l->first = n;
    } else {
        l->first = n;
        l->last = n;
    }
    l->count++;
}

void list_push_last(List l, void *data)
{
    struct node *n;

    n = calloc(1, sizeof(*n));
    assert(n);
    n->data = data;
    if(l->count > 1) {
        list_bond(l->last, n);
        l->last = n;
    } else {
        l->first = n;
        l->last = n;
    }
    l->count++;
}

/* if count == 0 return NULL! */
static struct node *list_find_nth(List l, unsigned int c)
{
    struct node *tmp;
    unsigned int i;

    assert(c <= l->count+1);
    if(l->count == 0)
        return NULL;

    if(c<=l->count/2) {
        tmp = l->first;
        for(i = 1; i<c; i++) {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    } else {
        tmp = l->last;
        for(i = l->count; i>=c; i--) {
            tmp = tmp->prev;
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}

void list_append_nth(List l, void *data, unsigned int c)
{
    struct node *n;
    struct node *tmp;

    n = calloc(1, sizeof(*n));
    assert(n);
    n->data = data;

    assert(c <= l->count+1);
    tmp = list_find_nth(l, c);

    if(tmp != NULL) {
        n->prev = tmp;
        n->next = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = n;
        if(n->next != NULL)
            n->next->prev = n;
    } else {
        l->first = n;
        l->last = n;
    }
    l->count++;
}

void *list_pop_first(List l)
{
    void *data = NULL;
    struct node *tmp;
    if(l->count != 0) {
        tmp = l->first;
        data = tmp->data;
        if (l->count == 1) {
            l->first = NULL;
            l->last = NULL;
        } else {
            l->first = l->first->next;
            l->first->prev = NULL;
        }
        free(tmp);
        l->count--;
    }
    return data;
}

void *list_pop_last(List l)
{
    void *data = NULL;
    struct node *tmp;
    if(l->count != 0) {
        tmp = l->last;
        data = tmp->data;
        if(l->count > 1) {
            l->last = l->last->prev;
            l->last->next = NULL;
        } else {
            l->last = NULL;
            l->first = NULL;
        }
        free(tmp);
        l->count--;
    }
    return data;
}

void *list_pop_nth(List l, unsigned int c)
{
    void *data = NULL;
    struct node *tmp;
    if(l->count != 0) {
        tmp = list_find_nth(l, c);
        data = tmp->data;
        if(l->count > 1) {
            tmp->prev->next = tmp->next;
            tmp->next->prev = tmp->prev;
        } else {
            l->last = NULL;
            l->first = NULL;
        }
        free(tmp);
        l->count--;
    }
    return data;
}

/* split lists in half */
static void list_split(List left, List right)
{
    struct node *n;
    if(left->count > 2) {
        n = list_find_nth(left, left->count/2);
        right->first = n->next;
        right->last = left->last;
        right->count = left->count - left->count/2;
        left->count = left->count/2;
        left->last = n;
        n->next->prev = NULL;
        n->next = NULL;
    } else {
        right->last = left->last;
        right->first = left->last;
        left->last = left->first;
        left->last->next = NULL;
        right->first->prev = NULL;
        left->count = 1;
        right->count = 1;
    }
}

/* print data in list */
void list_print(List l, print f)
{
    unsigned int i;
    struct node *tmp;
    if(l->count != 0) {
        tmp = l->first;
        for(i = 0;i<l->count;i++) 
        {
            f(tmp->data);
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }
}

/*
 * DO NOT DELETE (yet)
 * for debugging info about list
 */
void list_debug(List l, print f)
{
    struct node *tmp;
    int i;
    i = 0;
    tmp = l->first;
    printf("List: count %d, first %d, last %d\n", l->count, l->first, l->last);
    while (tmp!= NULL) {
        printf("%d. node. Data: ",i);
        f(tmp->data);
        printf("at address %d. Next: %d Prev: %d \n",tmp,tmp->next,tmp->prev);
        tmp = tmp->next;
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

static inline List list_merge(List left, List right, List_compare cmp)
{
    struct node *tmp_right;
    struct node *tmp_left;
    List result;
    void *val = NULL;
    result = list_create();

    /* get first element (smallest or biggest debending on cmp) of two lists and add it to result */
    if (cmp(left->first->data, right->first->data) <= 0) {
        result->first = left->first;
        result->last = left->first;
        tmp_right = result->first->next;
        tmp_left = right->first;
    } else {
        result->first = right->first;
        result->last = right->first;
        tmp_right = result->first->next;
        tmp_left = left->first;
    }

    /* Run through left and right lists to append another nodes to result till one of them is empty */
    while(tmp_right != NULL && tmp_left != NULL) {
        if(cmp(tmp_right->data, tmp_left->data) <= 0) {
            list_bond(result->last, tmp_right);
            result->last = tmp_right;
            tmp_right = tmp_right->next;
        } else {
            list_bond(result->last, tmp_left);
            result->last = tmp_left;
            tmp_left = tmp_left->next;
        }
    }

    /* append the remaining nodes of one of the lists */
    if(tmp_right == NULL) {
        list_bond(result->last, tmp_left);
        result->last = left->last;
    }
    if(tmp_left == NULL) {
        list_bond(result->last, tmp_right);
        result->last = right->last;
    }
    result->count = left->count +right->count;

    list_destroy(left);
    list_destroy(right);

    return result;
}

List list_merge_sort(List left, List_compare cmp)
{
    List right, sort_left, sort_right;

    if(left->count <= 1) {
        return left;
    }

    right = list_create();

    list_split(left,right);

    sort_left = list_merge_sort(left, cmp);
    sort_right = list_merge_sort(right, cmp);

    return list_merge(sort_left, sort_right, cmp);
}
```

src/dllist.h

```
#ifndef dllist_h
#define dllist_h
/* basic list type */
typedef struct list *List;
typedef int (*List_compare)(const void *a, const void *b);

typedef void (print)(void *);
/* function prototypes generated by cproto */
#include "dllist.p"

#endif
```

src/test_list.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <values.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "dllist.h"

#define TEST_SIZE (1000000)

int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return (*(const int *)a > *(const int *)b);
}

void printnum(void *a)
{
    printf("%d ",*(int *)a);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    List l;
    int *data;
    int i;
    int a;
    int *r;
    time_t t;

    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;

    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    data = calloc(TEST_SIZE, sizeof(*data));
    a = rand()%1000;

    for(i = 0;i<TEST_SIZE;i++)
    {
        data[i] = rand()%1000;
    }

    l = list_create();
    for(i = TEST_SIZE/2-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        list_push_first(l,&data[i]);
    }
    for(i = TEST_SIZE/2;i<TEST_SIZE;i++)
    {
        list_push_last(l,&data[i]);
    }

    l = list_merge_sort(l, &compare);

    for(i = 0;i<TEST_SIZE;i++)
    {
        r = list_pop_first(l);
    }
    list_destroy(l);
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

src/Makefile

```
# variables. SOURCES is exported from makefile one folder up and so is DEBUG
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
PROTO=$(SOURCES:.c=.p)
STATPROTO=$(SOURCES:.c=.sp)
DEPS=$(SOURCES:.c=.d)

# Generate and include dependencies:

all: $(DEPS) $(OBJECTS)

%.o: %.c %.d
    $(CC) $(WARNINGS) $(DEBUG) $(COMPILER) -c -o $@ $<

%.d: %.c
    $(CC) -MM -MG -MF $@ $<

# Generate function prototypes
%.p: %.c
    cproto $< > $@
%.sp: %.c
    cproto -S $< > $@

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(DEPS) $(PROTO) $(STATPROTO)

-include $(DEPS)
```

and Makefile

```
# IMPORTANT variables
PROGRAMNAME=Game
SOURCES=test_list.c dllist.c

#locations
SRCDIR= src
OUTDIR= bin
TESTDIR=tests

OBJECTS= $(addprefix $(SRCDIR)/, $(SOURCES:.c=.o))
PROGRAM= $(addprefix $(OUTDIR)/, $(PROGRAMNAME))

WARNINGS= -W -Wall -ansi -Wextra -pedantic -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes # turn on all possible warnings
COMPILER= -std=gnu89 -s -Os -Ofast -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections      # strip, optimize for size and for performance. After that place all functions and data to separate sections
LINKER= -Wl,-Map=$(PROGRAM).map,--cref,--gc-section -Wl,--build-id=none     # and with linker delete unneeded ones
DEBUG= -g

export SOURCES
export DEBUG
export COMPILER
export WARNINGS

all: $(PROGRAM)

.PHONY: objects clean
objects:
    $(MAKE) -C $(SRCDIR) all

$(PROGRAM): objects
    cc -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(DEBUG) $(LINKER)
    strip -S --strip-all --remove-section=.note.gnu.gold-version --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.note --remove-section=.note.gnu.build-id --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag $@

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(SRCDIR) clean
    $(MAKE) -C $(TESTDIR) clean
    rm -f $(PROGRAM) $(PROGRAM).map
```

Comment: You might want to remove all the commented out lines of code. It's obviously for debugging. You probably should take the tour as well.

Comment: Sorry, better now? What tour?

Comment: Much better. The tour is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you get under a second for whole process execution it's better to start timing inside the program using a accurate timestamp function. This avoids the C runtime initialization and printing from dominating the measurement.

One suggestion I had was keeping a `struct node *freelist` so you can easily grab a new node by doing

```
struct node *newNode = freelist;
freelist = freelist->next;
```

And when you free a node you can add it to the free list by doing:

```
oldNode->next = freelist;
freelist = oldNode;
```

This avoids having to call `calloc` and `free` over and over.

---

If you destroy a non empty list you leak all nodes still in the list. Similarly the `rightlist` in `list_split` just gets its values overwritten.

Comment: The first bug I saw earlier but somehow forgot about it. But list_split is static, so nobody sees it so it should be ok, right?
Anyway thanks for nice suggestion, I'll try to implement that.

Comment: There should at least be a assert that the right list is empty or let it return a new right list.